# Storing content in a buffer

Tags: java, xml

What is the function that allows me to store the contents of

```
current.getChild("C").getContent(0)
```

in a table?

Comment: this is no way for asking a question. What language are you using? is it an HTML table,java table, other? Post a complete code sample.

Comment: i use java language , i'd like to store the resulat of current.getChild("C").getContent(0) in a buffer                          example: current.getChild("C").getContent(0) return "this is a result", i'd like to store each string in a case of the buffer

Comment: i'm a beginner with stackoverflow , how can i accept answer ?

Comment: @researcher http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

For example :

```
 ArrayList<String> listNodeContent= new ArrayList<String>();

 //your code

 listNodeContent.add(current.getChild("C").getContent(0));
```

Then you can retrieve the content using different methods : [ArrayList#get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29), with an iterator ([ArrayList#iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator%28%29)) or with a foreach loop :

```
 for(String tmp : listNodeContent){
      System.out.println(tmp);
 }
```

Comment: i have used your code , it returns [[Text: 
            This is a result
         ]]                                                                 I want that each string in a case of the buffer.Thank you. i have just modify this instruction listNodeContent.add(current.getChild("C").getContent(0).toString());

Comment: listNodeContent.get(0) also return  [[Text: This is a result ]]

Comment: @researcher What do you expect `listNodeContent.get(0)` to return? I don't really understand what do you mean by "each string", you mean each words?

Comment: yes i want each word of 'This is a result' in a case of the buffer.. thank you

Comment: Try `current.getChild("C").getContent(0).toString().split(" ")` it will give you an array with each word.

Comment: @researcher Also if you want an ArrayList you can do that : `listNodeContent.addAll(Arrays.asList(current.getChild("C").getContent(0).toString().split(" ")))`